Is there anything special about the dome nuts on a Nexus hub?
I've just bought a Dahon Vitesse folding bike (a few years old) and I'm sorting out some annoyances.
One small but surprisingly tricky thing is that the back axle nuts stick out quite a long way beyond the pannier rack, making fitting a pannier a rather awkward two-handed task (it should be single-handed with that pannier's nice quick-release mechanism).  They're dome nuts (AKA acorn nuts I think), and rather tall ones at that.  I'd like to replace the drive-side one with something lower, as that's the side where I fit my pannier every day - you can fold the bike with the pannier attached that way. I'll have the wheel off anyway to upgrade the tyre, even if I don't service the hub just yet.
So, before I grab any old 3/8"-26 nut from my stash of old bike parts, is there anything special about the nuts, noting that the drive side has an anti-rotation washer under it?

The dome is a cosmetic and safety feature that hides the projecting threads and limits things getting sliced up by the axle. Any suitable axle nut should be fine unless there’s something particularly unique about the domed ones on the bike.

@WarrenBurton that's what I'm thinking. It's an unusually tall dome, and tucked away, but I think I'll keep it on the other side where it's more likely to hit me for a few reasons. No dome nuts on the front though, but the axle sticks out less than a turn beyond the normal nut and isn't sharp
